# Production push notification generation

Tags: ios5, push-notification

I have created push notification development certificates successfully, but now I need to create production ones. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming guide? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1